# Firebase: Very Slow data show on Label text

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to observe information from my firebase database and store it in a dictionary, the problem is when I try to show these data on a label it takes a lot of time about 30 seconds, can you solve it please.

```
@objc func fetchUser() {

    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {

        let uid = user.uid
        let email = user.email

        ref?.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print(dictionary)
                self.disName.text! = dictionary["DisplayName"] as! String
            }
        })

        disUID.text = uid
        disEmail.text = email
    }
}
```

Comment: if the connection is fast but your label is still slow, put it in main queue: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.disName.text! = dictionary["DisplayName"] as! String }`

Comment: @ngbaanh i tried that before makes no different , i can see the dictionary printed very fast in the debugger but i don't understand why it takes so long to show it on the label

Comment: That's so weird. I am still wondering why do you use `!` in this case. I think it should be `self.disName.text = dictionary["DisplayName"] as? String`

Comment: xcode auto correction did that

Comment: Please remove that `!`